# HDMI connection transfers interface only, not content or cursor (arrow)

Tags: hdmi

When connecting an HDMI cable from my new ACER laptop to a two-year old TV, what appears on the TV screen is the Ubuntu interface, including the left-hand menu icons, but not the cursor and NOT the content.

I found an old Bogie movie, Caine Mutiny, on YouTube, downloaded it using Mozilla's download helper, and saved it to "files." I try playing it back on the ACER, and it worked fine.

But when I go through an HDMI-HDMI cable to the TV, the movie does not come out, neither the video nor the audio.  A picture of the Ubuntu interface is there, with all of the left-side icons, but not cursor.

I've tried an HDMI-to-VGA cable, plus a separate audio cable, with the same results.

We went through many, many old Laurel & Hardy movies this way with an old Dell laptop (Win-7) without problems, using the old VGA system.  The Dell eventually died and I replaced it with a new ACER with a bare-bones Linus installed (no interface for newbies like me).  I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and everything seems to run fine.

Comment: It sounds like you're in dual-screen mode. You need to change the settings, in Ubuntu, of your second monitor to mirror your primary display, rather than extend it.

Comment: Under "All Settings" and "Displays," clicking at "Mirror displays" produces nothing.

Comment: Hi Georgie, The question is a little vague even the title is not quite clear. I would consider a more concise title and a little less story to the problem.